# Whenever a product is added to cart an additional qty of same product should be added to cart

Tags: magento2

Should be achieved by preference not using the plugin and observer

Comment: Did you just copied the ticket description that was assigned to you :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a preference for `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add::execute`

Or you can create a plugin for

```
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\RequestQuantityProcessor::prepareQuantity
```

Check if the current request is add in plugin ode

And update the **qty** as per your logic