# Whenever a product is added to cart an additional qty of same product should be added to cart using prefrence not plugin?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, preference, qty

> Should be achieved by preference not using the plugin and observer.
> can anyone provide code for this ?

Comment: Using 'preference' should always be your last option, you should always choose plugin or observer as your first choice

Comment: This question is already answered. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/357360/whenever-a-product-is-added-to-cart-an-additional-qty-of-same-product-should-be

Comment: Okay  @MagePal Extensions I think this is not right question that guy is new on magento exchange so accept solution .
 Can you describe code here ?

Answer (score 0):

See [Whenever a product is added to cart an additional qty of same product should be added to cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/357360/whenever-a-product-is-added-to-cart-an-additional-qty-of-same-product-should-be)

Option 1 - (Don't recommend)

You can create a preference for

> Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add
> and modify the `execute` method

Option 2 - (Strongly recommend)

Create a before plugin for

> Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\RequestQuantityProcessor::prepareQuantity

then check if the current request and update the qty as per your logic

Comment: Okay Thanks @MagePal Extensions